# how to export HTML "innerHTML" with attributes to text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on HTML export option from a DIV tag including the elements and attributes,

**HTML:**

```
<div id="master"><span class="classname">content goes here</span></div>
<span class="download" onclick="calldownload()">Download</span>
```

**JS:**

```
function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType  +  ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click(); 
}

var filename = 'output.html';

function calldownload(){
    downloadInnerHtml(filename, 'master', 'text/html');
}
```

**Output:**

```
<span>Content goes here<span>
```

**Required Output:**

```
<span class="classname">Content goes here<span>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you edit the question to remove the error that the answers pointed out?

Comment: Thats not answer, Thats just like clearing some errors in the question but that is not the answer

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4d57xja6/1/

Comment: I'm sorry. So I recommend you to unaccept my answer back, for other users will answer you. (if they will see you accept my question they will not try answer you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is wrong.
 you have wrote :

```
      <span="className">
```

instead of

```
      <span class="className">
```

Comment: Thanks for the catchup, sorry for the missup !

Comment: If my answer helped you I'wll be happy you will accpet it

Comment: That is my question only but that doesn't resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="master"><span="classname">content goes here</span></div>
```

in this line  section is not understandable for HTML. You should define attribute name like class, id, style etc..

```
<div id="master"><span id="classname">content goes here</span></div>

<div id="master"><span class="classname">content goes here</span></div>
```

etc...